# How to search data in AWS amplify datastore using @searchable in Android (Java)?

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, android-studio, aws-amplify

I read this documentation:
https://docs.amplify.aws/cli-legacy/graphql-transformer/searchable/#definition

But how to implement the query in Android Studio using Java? What are the methods of Amplify to get search query?

Answer (score 0):

```
Amplify.DataStore.query(
   Product.class,
   items -> {
       while (items.hasNext()) {
           Product item = items.next();
           Log.i("Amplify", "Id " + item.getId());
       }
   },
   failure -> Log.e("Amplify", "Could not query DataStore", failure)
```

);

You can check full doc here
https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/data-access/q/platform/android/#create-and-update

And some examples here
https://github.com/enlearacademy/chatme-android-amplify
https://aws.amazon.com/es/getting-started/hands-on/build-android-app-amplify/